# Is it possible to use the (polyData) writers in VTK for data types from other libraries?

Tags: c++, vtk

I am using ParaView for data visualization, and therefore I need to write my own data in a supported format (like ASCII .vtk). For this purpose, I wrote a legacy ASCII .vtk writer , and it's working fine. However, since I wrote a write-intensive application that runs in parallel, I would like to try out the vtk XML writer.

Is possible to re-use the writers with Classes that come from another library?

From looking at the [vtkPolyDataWriter documentation](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyDataWriter.html), I noticed that VTK is object oriented and that the writers rely heavily on the "Visualization Pipeline" flow using ports, e.g.:

```
 353     vtkNew<vtkPolyDataWriter> writer0;
 354     writer0->SetFileName( "./hyperTreeGridContour.vtk" );
 355     writer0->SetInputConnection( contour->GetOutputPort() );
 356     writer0->Write();
```

from [vtkPolyData Example](http://vtk.org/gitweb?p=VTK.git;a=blob;f=Examples/HyperTree/Cxx/HyperTreeGridDemonstrator.cxxhttp://).

Is it then possible to re-use [the writers](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkWriter.html) with classes outside VTK hierarchy?

The writeable object should be a vtkObject, but [vtkPolyData](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyData.html#a47cd25a22735630cecd990ed22e64f76) class, that gets written out at the end, relies even further on VTK specific types.

Comment: I guess you could write your own class which inherits from vtkPolyData (and possibly other datatypes you are using) and implements the necessary functions?

Comment: @Dan thanks, but the data structures such as PointList (generally speaking) are already set and fixed(although generic) in the library I'm woring in. I expected the writers to be generic and that I just have to either adapt my interface or the iterators to the datatype elements. There are clearly concepts ready for abstraction in VTK: Polygon, Point, etc...To me it's a bit suprising that the types are fixed.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to use one of the VTK writer classes to write out data from your own internal storage layout. This is not a sensible approach, as the VTK writers were designed to work within the overall VTK framework. The only sensible way of achieving the goal lies in the answer with Hal, if you insist on using the VTK writer classes. If you insist in just sticking with your own data storage framework, then the best solution is to write your own writer from scratch. As Hal says, do not prejudge speed until you've tried it.

Answer (score 2):

No need to do anything fancy.  Just have a WriteVTKPolyData() method that makes use of the VTK classes.

```
#include <vtkXMLPolyDataWriter.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkCellArray.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkVersion.h>
#include <vtkPoints.h>
class MyClass {
  /* ... */
public:
  void WriteVTKPolyData(const char * file_name) const;
};
void MyClass::WriteVTKPolyData(const char * file_name) const {
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polyData =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
  // EXAMPLE CODE POPULATING VTKPOLYDATA
  points->InsertNextPoint(+1, +1, +1);
  points->InsertNextPoint(-1, -1, +1);
  points->InsertNextPoint(-1, +1, -1);
  points->InsertNextPoint(+1, -1, -1);
  polyData->SetPoints(points);
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> polys  =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();
  vtkIdType cell[3];
  cell[0] = 0; cell[1] = 2; cell[2] = 1;
  polys->InsertNextCell(3,cell);
  cell[0] = 1; cell[1] = 2; cell[2] = 3;
  polys->InsertNextCell(3,cell);
  cell[0] = 2; cell[1] = 0; cell[2] = 3;
  polys->InsertNextCell(3,cell);
  cell[0] = 3; cell[1] = 0; cell[2] = 1;
  polys->InsertNextCell(3,cell);
  polyData->SetPolys(polys);
  // END EXAMPLE CODE POPULATING
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataWriter> writer =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataWriter>::New();
  writer->SetFileName(file_name);
  #if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
  writer->SetInput(polyData);
  #else
  writer->SetInputData(polyData);
  #endif
  writer->Write();
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  MyClass myObject;
  myObject.WriteVTKPolyData("out.vtp");
}
```

If you want to keep the points and polygons in memory as you edit them:

```
#include <vtkXMLPolyDataWriter.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkCellArray.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkVersion.h>
#include <vtkPoints.h>
class MyClass {
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> m_PolyData;
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> m_Points;
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> m_Polygons;
  /* ... */
public:
  /* ... */
  MyClass();
  void WriteVTKPolyData(const char * file_name) const;
  void f();
};
MyClass::MyClass() :
  m_PolyData(vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New()),
  m_Points(vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New()),
  m_Polygons(vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New())
{
  m_PolyData->SetPoints(m_Points);
  m_PolyData->SetPolys(m_Polygons);
}
void MyClass::f() {
  // EXAMPLE CODE POPULATING VTKPOLYDATA
  m_Points->InsertNextPoint(+1, +1, +1);
  m_Points->InsertNextPoint(-1, -1, +1);
  m_Points->InsertNextPoint(-1, +1, -1);
  m_Points->InsertNextPoint(+1, -1, -1);
  vtkIdType cell[3];
  cell[0] = 0; cell[1] = 2; cell[2] = 1;
  m_Polygons->InsertNextCell(3,cell);
  cell[0] = 1; cell[1] = 2; cell[2] = 3;
  m_Polygons->InsertNextCell(3,cell);
  cell[0] = 2; cell[1] = 0; cell[2] = 3;
  m_Polygons->InsertNextCell(3,cell);
  cell[0] = 3; cell[1] = 0; cell[2] = 1;
  m_Polygons->InsertNextCell(3,cell);
  // END EXAMPLE CODE POPULATING
}
void MyClass::WriteVTKPolyData(const char * file_name) const {
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataWriter> writer =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataWriter>::New();
  writer->SetFileName(file_name);
  #if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
  writer->SetInput(m_PolyData);
  #else
  writer->SetInputData(m_PolyData);
  #endif
  writer->Write();
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  MyClass myObject;
  myObject.f();
  myObject.WriteVTKPolyData("out.vtp");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hal, but this would be very expensive to do in my case, since I would need to translate all the cell-face-point information to VTK datastructures.

Comment: I say try it and find out how slow it is.  After all, you are probably not going to be calling this function more than once.

Comment: well , I'm storing simulation data in VTK POLYDATA format, it is consisted of hundreds of thousands of polygons (there is really no upper limit), and it is often changed (computed), so actually I am computing and writing it quite often, and its huge. However, thanks for the hint anyway, I will try it + benchmark the code.